# JavaScript loading function script to display django static image

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an image processing that takes some seconds and I want to show a loading gif and a text until it's done and the view changes.

So, after selecting an image, when pressing the **Submit** button to upload it, I call the following JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoading(e) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "{% static 'img/loading.gif' %}";
        div.innerHTML = "Processing...";
        div.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 40%; z-index: 5000; width: 422px; text-align: center; background: #106087; border: 1px solid #000';
        div.appendChild(img);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        return true;
}
```

and the form for uploading image looks like:

```
<form  onsubmit="ShowLoading()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The problem is that after pressing the Submit button, **the div and the text appear**, but **the photo doesn't.**

I have the **loading.gif** file in my /static/img/

I also included `{% load static %}` in my code header. (and the path to static files is set in settings - and it's working in html code)

The JavaScript script is in the same html file as the form that's using the function.

I get the following error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 38150)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/raul/pic2formpoc/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/raul/pic2formpoc/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: If you look at the source code in the browser, what's the final path for `img.src` in that script? (also, I'd add the loading HTML to the document but have it invisible initially, then simply turn it visible in the function)

Comment: the path in the browser is correct "/static/img/loading.gif". how can I do it that way?

Comment: I think the main problem is that unless you're sending the form via AJAX (and it doesn't look that way), the browser is basically already looking at the current view as discarded, since submitting a form will load a new page. Maybe the browser doesn't run the HTTP request for the image because it's already loading a new page anyway. As for my alternative, just add the `<div>` and its contents using `<div style="display: none">` to your HTML, then remove everything from your function except for the `div.style.cssText = '...` line